# Passar objeto para WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento utilizando WebService + Windows Form e fiz alguns métodos bobos passando parâmetros, porem, me surgiu a ideia de passar um objeto como parâmetro onde o Web Service iria me retorna uma string qualquer concatenando cada dado, até ai tudo bem. O problema é, como posso passar um Objeto que esta na Solução Windows Form para o WebService?

Ambos teriam que ter a mesma classe básica?

Fiz mais ou menos assim no Windows Form:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Funcionario.FuncionarioSoapClient func = new Funcionario.FuncionarioSoapClient();
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c.Nome = "JR";
        c.Idade = 20;
        func.Concatena(c);

    }
```

Mas me retorna o erro: cannot convert from 'WebService...' to 'WebSerivce...'

No geral, como faço isso? passar um objeto do windows form para o webservice?

Comment: Depende. Qual o tipo de webservice que você tem? WCF, ASMX ou ASP.NET WebAPI?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível passar um objeto para o `webservice`.

Você tem que converter o objeto para string e enviar a string para o webservice e no webservice converter a string em um objeto novamente.

Normalmente eu utilizo Json para transformar o objeto em string.